# LGBM Classification Threshold

Tags: lightgbm

I am working on a binary classification problem using LightGbm in Python.

Is there a way to set the threshold for binary classification?

I have seen this done for logistic regression and Random Forrest.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what exactly is your problem here and if it is regarding code that you've already tried.

Do you mean that you'd like to set a threshold, which would set all the prediction scores from e.g. 0.4 (instead of 0.5) and below to 0 and from 0.4 and above to 1? If so, don't use `predict` function, but `predict_proba` and create a function yourself that based on defined threshold will change the "probability" to final decision.